# twitteR API for R

Tags: r, api, web-scraping, twitter

I want to use Twitter API for R:

I'm using the following R Library-

```
library(twitteR)
```

I made my Twitter Developer Account and generate access_token, access_secret, consumer_secret, consumer_key.

```
consumer_key <- XXXXX
consumer_secret <- XXXXX
access_token <- XXXXX
access_secret <- XXXXX

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

Every time I'm facing the same error:

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

I read over stack exchange that I need to load the library `base64enc`. I tried doing that but still gave the same error.

Kindly suggest some movearounds.

Comment: I've created a R client for Twitter API using OpenAPI Generator: https://github.com/wing328/r-twitter/. Please give it a try to see if it works for you.